# Drawing and Plotting graph in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Does OpenCV provide a function on how to draw and plot a graph?

I found this link by Shervin Emami http://www.shervinemami.info/graphs.html which was created by himself.

Comment: please avoid links..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can see OpenCV doesn't provide a function as part of its API to draw and plot graphs, in the form of cvDrawPlot(cvMat* data, other args...).

Most plotting samples seen using only OpenCV function calls involving making a plot as if were any other image with `cvCreateImage`.

Then they iterate through data and fill the image with OpenCV primites like `cvRectangle`, `cvLine`, `cvCircle` and `cvPoint`.

Then they call `cvShowImage` to display the created plot image.

If the library you found does what you want then you can use it.

You can also write the data to a file and call an external plotting tool like gnuplot or call functions that draw and plot graphs using other visualisation or plotting libraries like VTK or plplot.

Another library other than the one you have found is [cvplot](http://code.google.com/p/cvplot/).

Comment: It may also be easiest to output the data to a .csv file an import it into Excel then plot the graph.

Answer (score 11):

you can try this:
https://code.google.com/p/cvplot/

Matlab style plot functions for OpenCV, based on highgui.
By the way, it's for C++ only.

It's open source.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the cvplot. but thanks. The program I tried on Shervin works perfectly as well. It just that I can view the x and y axis values.

Answer (score 4):

A rather crude but do-it-yourself approach, would be entail plotting the line graph on cv::Mat image:

```
template <typename T>
cv::Mat plotGraph(std::vector<T>& vals, int YRange[2])
{

    auto it = minmax_element(vals.begin(), vals.end());
    float scale = 1./ceil(*it.second - *it.first); 
    float bias = *it.first;
    int rows = YRange[1] - YRange[0] + 1;
    cv::Mat image = Mat::zeros( rows, vals.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    image.setTo(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)vals.size()-1; i++)
    {
        cv::line(image, cv::Point(i, rows - 1 - (vals[i] - bias)*scale*YRange[1]), cv::Point(i+1, rows - 1 - (vals[i+1] - bias)*scale*YRange[1]), Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
    }

    return image;
}
```

Usage example:

```
vector<int> numbers(100);
std::iota (numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);

int range[2] = {0, 100};
cv::Mat lineGraph = plotGraph(numbers, range);
```

One can then use [`imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) or [Image Watch](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e682d542-7ef3-402c-b857-bbfba714f78d) to view the graph

Comment: Keep in mind that API has changed (I'm using OpenCV 3.0) and `cv::line` became `cvLine`. Method signature changed too.

Comment: I check this in the new documentation. Are you sure about this? http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html#line

Comment: I see... This really sound strange, because in my C++ program it says `'line': identifier not found`

Comment: Try cv::line and don't forget to #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

Comment: `'line': is not a member of 'cv'`. Moreover, `C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2/highgui.hpp(130): note: see declaration of 'cv'`

Comment: Look at core.hpp on line 2589 `CV_EXPORTS_W void line(CV_IN_OUT Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0);`

Answer (score 3):

No. It does not. There is a [plot contrib module](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/plot), but it is very basic.

You could try Profactor CvPlot https://github.com/Profactor/cv-plot. (I am the developer). It is very easy to integrate, purely opencv based and can be extended with custom controls. This is how you can plot to a cv::Mat or show a diagram with an interactive viewer:

```cpp
#include <CvPlot/cvplot.h>
std::vector<double> x(20*1000), y1(x.size()), y2(x.size()), y3(x.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    x[i] = i * CV_2PI / x.size();
    y1[i] = std::sin(x[i]);
    y2[i] = y1[i] * std::sin(x[i]*50);
    y3[i] = y2[i] * std::sin(x[i]*500);
}
auto axes = CvPlot::makePlotAxes();
axes.create<CvPlot::Series>(x, y3, "-g");
axes.create<CvPlot::Series>(x, y2, "-b");
axes.create<CvPlot::Series>(x, y1, "-r");

//plot to a cv::Mat
cv::Mat mat = axes.render(300, 400);

//or show with interactive viewer
CvPlot::show("mywindow", axes);
```

[image: CvPlot]

You may also want to try [Leonardvandriel's cvplot](https://github.com/leonardvandriel/cvplot). It works similar but cannot be extended with custom drawables.

Comment: Do not post a link to a tool or library as an answer. Demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself. Do [edit] the answer, and flag for undeletion once you have added the demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/leonardvandriel/cvplot. You can plot graphs with little configuration and it supports multiple graphs in a single window. (Note: blatant self-promotion).

Comment: cvplot looks really nice!