# Plot graphs in OpencCV

Tags: c++, opencv, graph, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing and Plotting graph in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250079/drawing-and-plotting-graph-in-opencv)

How can I plot a single row of an image using OpenCV? I found some libs like http://www.shervinemami.info/graphs.html, but are there any libs that use opencv2 library (cv:: functions, core-module and so on...)

Comment: the libraries in "Drawing and Plotting graph in OpenCV" use opencv1 functions like iplimage. I am using opencv2 functions in my project and don't want to mix them.

Comment: @marc you won't believe, but there are these function in opencv2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't.

OpenCV is for reading and interpreting images.

Use a drawing library - or better still a graph-drawing library.

What platform are you on? Some cross-platform ones are here:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/libxmi/libxmi.html
- http://www.boutell.com/gd/
- http://www.levien.com/libart/

Specifically for charts and graphs, see this question:

- [C++: Free easy way to draw graphs and charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765408/c-free-easy-way-to-draw-graphs-and-charts)

Comment: -1: [this is](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_geometric_drawing/basic_geometric_drawing.html) enough to plot any graph without using other 3rdparty libs.

Comment: @astor, it is still a bad tool for the job.

Comment: @Astor, Because the api is so poor for doing graphs or graphics! If you want to draw a graph, get a graph library which will let you do every kind of graph very easily - hand it a bunch of data and a few parameters and Voila! A pie chart! If you want to do generic drawing get a drawing library - gradients, fills, clipping, all at your fingertips!

Comment: It's not poor - last time I draw math graphics using opencv without any problems and very quickly (drawing lines was enough!). Also author wants just to draw graph not chart etc (read the question). Anyway I don't want to continue argue with you on this topic.

Comment: @Astor, if the author wants to draw little tick marks on the axes, this will be a lot of work without a chart drawing library.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I will try some of your links. I could indeed use extended graph settings.

Comment: @marc, see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765408/c-free-easy-way-to-draw-graphs-and-charts